RN Error during bundling while setting SVG
I'm a student new to React Native. I was setting up the svg library to use the svg file to create a hands-on project with TypeScrit. However, when I insert those libraries, the same error occurs. How do I solve this?
The environment I use and package.json are as follows.
os : window useing tool : VSC target : android emulator with android studio, API 34
package.json
{
  "name": "MyApp2",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.4.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.17.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.10.7",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.32.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^15.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.74.85",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.74.85",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.74.85",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.34",
    "@types/styled-components-react-native": "^5.2.5",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.1.4",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "metro-config": "^0.80.9",
    "metro-runtime": "^0.80.9",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.4.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.11",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  }
}

The error is as follows.
error: Error: Unable to resolve module missing-asset-registry-path from C:\{personal address}\test\MyApp2\node_modules\@react-navigation\elements\lib\commonjs\assets\back-icon-mask.png: missing-asset-registry-path could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
  ..\..\..\node_modules
> 1 | �PNG
  2 | 
  3 |
  4 | IHDR2���gAMA���a cHRMz&�����u0�`:�p��Q<bKGD���̿tIME�
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\{personal address}\test\MyApp2\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:138:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\{personal address}\test\MyApp2\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:231:43)
    at C:\{personal address}\test\MyApp2\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:156:21
    at resolveDependencies (C:\{personal address}\test\MyApp2\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\buildSubgraph.js:42:25)
    at visit (C:\{personal address}\test\MyApp2\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\buildSubgraph.js:83:30)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 18)
    at async visit (C:\{personal address}\test\MyApp2\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\buildSubgraph.js:92:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 6)
    at async visit (C:\{personal address}\test\MyApp2\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\buildSubgraph.js:92:5)

The metro.config.js is as follows.

const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");

module.exports = (async () => {
    const {
        resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts },
    } = await getDefaultConfig();
    return {
        transformer: {
            getTransformOptions: async () => ({
                transform: {
                    experimentalImportSupport: false,
                    inlineRequires: true,
                },
            }),
            babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer"),
        },
        resolver: {
            assetExts: assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== "svg"),
            sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"],
        },
    };
})();

tsconfig is as follows.
{
  "extends": "@react-native/typescript-config/tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["src", "declaration.d.ts"]
}


declaration.d.ts is as follows.
declare module "*.svg" {
  import React from "react";
  import {SvgProps} from "react-native-svg";
  const content: React.FC<SvgProps>;
  export default content;
}

Thank you in advance for your answers.
Step-by-step execution and cache initialization with reference to official documents
